# RAID Controller Hardware compatability?

Tags: server, upgrade, hardware, raid, compatibility

I might be out of my element here, I am new to Ubuntu Server, and I am a intermediate Linux/Unix user, but zero experience with admin of such.  I am trying to build a server to play with for media sharing/streaming (Intel hardware Z77, 3770K).  I would like to add a SAS RAID controller card, but I am not able to find anything that says it will/won't work with Ubuntu.  I see some of the manufacturers say they work with Linux, or major Linux releases.  Is there a way to know for sure?  I could contact the manufacturers one by one, but I am curious if it supports Linux will it work in Ubuntu?  Is there a brand that works better or more consistently with Ubuntu like LSI, Adaptec, HP, Intel?  I am trying to add a PCIe x8 card.

Thank you :)

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check RAID supported hardware [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160905064203/http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/RAID/).

LSI Logic controllers are known to work without any problem.

Comment: Hi Sylvain.  Thanks for the reply.  I did see that list, but I read it as compatibility with integrated server solutions.  I am looking to purchase an aftermarket card.  Thanks for the comment about LSI - I was preferring that brand as it was, so I think I might try to stick with them.

Comment: The Ubuntu Certification program is for systems not devices, hence the limited list, sorry.

Comment: No no - please don't be sorry - I appreciated the response, and your comment about LSI was valuable and helpful.  Thank you still definitely applies :)

Comment: ok, please mark your question as answered if that guided you.

Answer (score 2):

[update, 12/29/20]. I know it's been a few years.  I also realize that I am not sure if I did, or how, to mark my question answered, hence why it may still be opened, so thought I would update in case it helps someone else.  I ended up using Avago (LSI Logic > Avago > Broadcomm) HBA adapters and in Ubuntu 16 through 20 (server and desktop) the cards work perfectly and I didn't need to install anything for them to work (no special drivers required).  I used 9211-8i, 9212-4i4e, (pair of) 9206-16e (which ran too hot for a non-server case, even though I had a boat load of fans, and added some to the card heat sink, but that's another story), and a (pair of) 9202-16e which I am using today on an old i7-4770K/Asus ROG mobo.  The list provided in the comments below by Sylvain were helpful and got me in the right direction to help make the selection.  I ended up using the HBA cards (IT mode) for static media to support about 50 TB of storage (backed up separately since the media doesn't change, no need for live mirroring, and no need for excessive performance, so no need to stripe it), and I also run 2 MDADM mirror arrays for 6TB and 10TB for desktop backups and critical storage needs.

The 9206-16e cards are x16 (physical) cards, PCIe 2.0, about 13 watts, and working in 2x x16 slots, that are running in x8 mode (max operation for the cards is x8 each).  I had tried the 9206-16e's because they were PCIe 3.0, and x8 cards (physical) running x8, but due to heat from about 28 watts per card, and insufficient air flow, they would shutdown when they overheated.  In any case, streaming multiple instances of 4K, 1080P (tested 1x 4K, 3x 1080P, and 2x 720p instances simultaneously) and the controller cards and the drivers had no issues keeping up.